# Are configuration files in Node&Express supposed to be read asynchronously?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, readfile

it is a naive question. 
Say you have a config file storing all you need for making a connection to your db. 
**If you are reading asynchronously, is the connection done in the callback?**

```
fs.readFile(pathToConfigFile, function (err, data){ createConnection(data);});
```

Does it look ugly, suspicious and bit dangerous, doesn't it? 
(This is an example, but I'd like to hear some opinions about it, if and why it is worng doing that and so on)
In my case I am using mongoose, I query the db on the schema object (i.e. User.find()...) so I simply get null results because the connection doesn't happen synchronously I guess.

Thank you very much

(here is my app-structure)

```
app.js 
db.js (read the config file and make the connection)
config.json (info of db and others)
user.js (model for users)
home.js (query all the users and list them on .get '/')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to so sync operations during app start up. However, do not do any sync stuff once the app has started, especially while handling requests.

Your app should be configured to start IF the database connectivity was successful.

```
// set up your app
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

....

// set up database connectiveity
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', function() {
  console.log('DB connectivity error')
  process.exit()
});
db.once('open', function() {

  // start your app now
  app.listen()

});
```

Answer (score 1):

create config.json like this:

**config.json**

```
module.exports = {
dbUrl:"mongodb://localhost/testDB",
serverPort: 9999
// add you other config key here
}
```

and require config file wherever you want to use like:

```
var config = require("./config");

console(config, config.severPort)
```

Suggestion: Use config module. It will read your config file as per the environment or default config file

Comment: As well, originally I did not want my configs to be Node specific, that is why I was handling it via a more gerenic readFile. But yours is the shortest and probably best approach. thanks

Comment: @desmogix you mentioned node & express in your question so I provided the answer for it.